# how to change image on next button click +iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to change image on next button click by using uiimage view. i am using following link to get images.

http://01s.in/webservices/ratemypic/getData.php?db_table=image

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
//Are you getting the image or not ...   
//if yes then  just make the button action method let say...... 

changeImage:(id)sender{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender
  [btn setImage:yourUIImage forControlState:UIControleStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use bellow line when you want to change button Image...

```
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"yourImageName"] forControlState:UIControleStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

First parse this string by using

```
NSArray *tempArry = [firstArryStr componentsSeparatedByString@".png"];
```

Now tempArray will contain image names.In button action you can use index(which is static var) to iterate this array and display image in imageview as follows:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png"],[tempArray objectAtIndex:index]];
index++;
```

and check whether index == [tempArray length], then reset it back to 0.Use this image in UIImageView.